# How to send JSON with byte array to web API / postman

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I want to be able to send to both

1. a Web API
2. Postman to Web API

I can do simple GET Requests to my Web API with Postman,  but what I don't understand is how to send a Byte Array.

With Postman, I know that it is a **PUT**

This is the Web API signature

```
[Route("api/Manifest/VerifyChain/")]
[ResponseType(typeof (VerifyManifestChainResponse))]
public IHttpActionResult PutVerifyManifestChain([FromBody] VerifyManifestChainRequest message)
{
   //.....
}
```

The Request class

```
public class VerifyManifestChainRequest
{
    public byte[] CalculatedMeasurement { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

Should I be sending a JSON via Raw Data using Postman?

```
{
   "CalculatedMeasurement": ?????,
   "DeviceId": "00022B9A000000010001"
}
```

I know when the Web page calls the Web API, I do see this in the Inspector

[image]

**Postman snippet**

[image]

How do I send data via Postman , and how do I send to a web API   http://localhost:42822/api/Manifest/VerifyChain/

Comment: maybe "CalculatedMeasurement" : [12,12,34,...] consider each item dont should be greather than 255

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 8):

In case you're looking for how to convert the file to a byte array for the postman request:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\myFile.txt");
string bytesStr = string.Join(",", bytes);
```

This will result into a long string that looks like this:

`"49,48,58,50,52,58,50,54,..."`

And then use it in the postman request like so:

```
{
    "FileBytes":[49,48,58,50,52,58,50,54],
    "DeviceId": 12345
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think your Webapi method needs [HttpPut]

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Manifest/VerifyChain/")]
[ResponseType(typeof (VerifyManifestChainResponse))]
public IHttpActionResult PutVerifyManifestChain([FromBody] VerifyManifestChainRequest message)
{
   //.....
}
```

and in postman your message body would be an array

```
{
  "CalculatedMeasurement":[71,107,98],
  "DeviceId": "afdghufsdjdf"
}
```

Comment: No bytes are to be converted in base 64.

Answer (score 2):

You must convert the file to base64 and send it as string.

1. Your WebAPI method is missing a the PUT indicator

```
    [HttpPut("api/Manifest/VerifyChain/")]
    [ResponseType(typeof (VerifyManifestChainResponse))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutVerifyManifestChain([FromBody] VerifyManifestChainRequest message)
    {
       //.....
    }
```

2. In Postman, I must use the body as JSON

[Request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEXhk.png)

Comment: This is the correct answer : convert the bytes in base 64 and use the resulting string in the postman request. For example, in java, converting bytes to base 64 is as easy as Base64.encode(myBytes).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Path("/{restaurantId}")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public byte[] getRestaurantById(@PathParam("restaurantId") final long restaurantId) {
    final Restaurant restaurant = restaurantService.getRestaurantById(restaurantId);

    if (null != restaurant) {
        return jsonObject.build(restaurant).asJson();
    }

    return jsonObject.build("Enter A Valid Restaurant Id").asJson();
}
```

this is the way to send the response back as byte[] it can be converted into json format in postman
what ever data you sent will be sent as byte[] when you debugg you can see this